# Create a loop in power query to create new columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have to add N number of columns to a table. The values within each of these N columns is based on certain values in the existing columns within the same table.

Is there a way to add these new colum s using a loop in power query.

Thanks,
Akshat

Comment: Give an example of input, desired output

Comment: do you want to add blank columns or columns with certain criteria? some sample input and output will help.